# Vulnerability test for CVE-2014-2483?

Tags: linux, penetration-test, java, vulnerability

I am in penetration testing on a server with Linux RHEL6/7 os. Vulnerability databases such as http://www.cvedetails.com/ mentioned the vulnerability CVE-2014-2483 for Java in Linux RHEL systems. I searched for the way that I can test my destination for the vulnerability, but I didn't find anything.

How can I test my server for this vulnerability?

Comment: “Applies to client deployment of Java only. This vulnerability can be exploited only through sandboxed Java Web Start applications and sandboxed Java applets.” - [Oracle Critical Patch Update Advisory - July 2014; Appendix - Oracle Fusion Middleware, Note 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/cpujul2014-1972956.html)

Comment: While looking for CVEs, you might want to prioritize those that have "exploit available".

Answer (score 1):

The best/most accurate way to test for things like this is in a white-box security assessment approach, by checking the version of Java installed on the system. So on a redhat system something like rpm -qa would provide the version installed, then check the changelogs for the package which should list what CVE's have been addressed.

To automate that, something like Nessus can be used with credentials to provide info. on what outdated packages are installed on a system.

If you're trying to do this "black box" they you'd need to dig into the exact details of the vuln (which may well be tricky if there has been no disclosure of the technical details, which is the case with many issues) and then see if it's remotely exploitable.

Answer (score 0):

There is an OpenVAS check that looks specifically for CVE-2014-2483.

http://plugins.openvas.org/index.php?oid=702987

Additional references can be found on [CVE Details](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve-details.php?t=1&cve_id=CVE-2014-2483#references).